# How to stop old list getting updated when updating new list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python, I am trying to solve following problem.

> Given a list, find even numbers and replace it with 2 of the same.

Sample input:

```
[2,5,4,0]
```

Sample output:

```
[2,2,5,4,4,0,0]
```

My solution:

```
l2 = [2,5,4,0]
def dupEven(l2):
    l3 = l2
    for i in l2:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            l3.insert(l3[i],i)
```

If I try to run the program, it is going in loop as it seems the old list (l1) keeps getting updated whenever the new list getting updated (l2).

How can I stop the old list getting updated when I update the new list in Python?

Comment: You don't have an old list and a new list. You have two references to one list.

Comment: (Also, you're inserting elements at the wrong indices.)

Comment: Ah, yes, I guess when I update the l3, the indices will change :(. Thanks.

Comment: That, and `l3[i]` is the wrong index from the start.

Comment: Sorry. from the start?
My expectation is `l3[i]` is basically as same as `l2[i]` (at least in the start). Isn't?

Comment: It is, but `l2[i]` is the wrong index. For example, on the first iteration, `i` is `2` and `l2[i]` is `4`, so you're trying to insert at index 4 instead of 0.